# Sweet Alert for Angular4 giving error on build

Tags: angular, sweetalert2

I am running angular4, sweet alert2. I get this error when I try to build with `ng build --prod`:

> src/app/devotions/devotions.component.ts(186,7): error TS2345: Argument of type '{ title: any; text: any; icon: string; confirmButtonText: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SweetAlertOptions & { useRejections: true; }'.

Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'icon' does not exist in

```
type 'SweetAlertOptions & { useRejections: true; }'.
```

This is my code. And this code is working. I just can't build

```
confirmAction(){
    swal({
        title: 'Confirm',
        text: "Would you like to edit this info?",
        type: 'question',
        showCancelButton: true,
        confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
        cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
        confirmButtonText: 'Edit',
        cancelButtonText: 'View',
        confirmButtonClass: 'btn btn-success',
        cancelButtonClass: 'btn btn-info',
        buttonsStyling: false,
        reverseButtons: true
    }).then((result) => {
        if (result.value) {
            document.getElementById('edit').click();
        } else if (// Read more about handling dismissals
        result.dismiss === swal.DismissReason.cancel
        ) {
            document.getElementById('view').click();
        }
        else{
            this.closeSwal();
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: Please post the whole error stack. And not as a picture.

Comment: If you have typings, Use the class to create object of the class and pass it on to swal function. Then its more type safety.

Answer (score 0):

try typing your options as any.

```
confirmAction(){
  swal({/* options */} as any).then(...)
```

Comment: Thank you. It was an error on my part. I had another swal() in which I had icon has option instead of type

Comment: @Yinka i have the same error, please can u specify what was the error?

Comment: @Aly Al Ameen I cant remeber what happend that day. Try and ensure u are not calling the swal function more than once on the same page. I think thats what caused it that day